# How to override browser data and set default value in woocommerce checkout page from fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I'm trying to set up default variable value in woocommerce checkout page

```php
$fields['address_1']['default'] = $cart_item['address'];
```

It works well only first time customer makes an order, when other order in process browser data is pre-filling fields, so i have used this

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value','__return_empty_string', 0, 0);
```

This filter returns with empty fields, but default value also returned empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try use instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_get_value', 'clear_shipping_fields_values', 5, 2 );
function clear_shipping_fields_values( $value, $input ) {
    $items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    $item  = reset( $items );

    if( is_checkout() && isset($item['address']) && in_array( $input, ['billing_address_1', 'shipping_address_1']) ) {
        $value = $item['address'];
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: that works thanks
but i have created different way.
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value','__return_empty_string', 0, 0); this function only clears wc fields, so If i use this filter it removes all default value, 
I have unset all of default checkout fields and created new fields, then wc won't save data on client side. Again thanks for you time

Comment: there is typo in the abovee code missing ) on
    if( is_checkout() && isset($item['address']) && in_array( $input, ['billing_address_1', 'shipping_address_1'] )) {

Comment: @govindak Oups! I have made a mistake when I have updated the answer afterwards… Updated … If this answer is useful for you and if you like/want, you could please upvote it… Thank you :)